# how to get dynamic select box value in nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

In My Express Application

**This is dynamic select box**

```
<div id="compare-box">
 <div class="col-sm-2" id="combo_1">
    <select name="meter_comp[]">
        <option value="none">-Select Meter-</option>
        <option value="5458c8de6c26bc741d41214b">MEDIDOR 01</option>
        <option value="5458c9fa539642e21d9bea49">MEDIDOR 02</option>
        <option value="545d3fd5cb00812c799b2280">Meter-demo 1</option>
    </select>
    <a class="close remove-meter">x</a>
  </div>
 <div class="col-sm-2" id="combo_2">
    <select name="meter_comp[]">
        <option value="none">-Select Meter-</option>
        <option value="5458c8de6c26bc741d41214b">MEDIDOR 01</option>
        <option value="5458c9fa539642e21d9bea49">MEDIDOR 02</option>
        <option value="545d3fd5cb00812c799b2280">Meter-demo 1</option>
    </select>
    <a class="close remove-meter">x</a>
 </div>
<a class="new-meter" href="javascript:;"> Add Meter</a>
```

**Post Handler**

```
 router.post('/',function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.meter_comp)
   });
```

**the first console gives**

```
{'meter_comp[]': [ '5458c8de6c26bc741d41214b', '5458ceab5af5d17b1e207d8c' ]}
```

**the second console gives**

```
 undefined
```

**I am Expecting like**

**first console**

```
{'meter_comp': [ '5458c8de6c26bc741d41214b', '5458ceab5af5d17b1e207d8c' ]}
```

**second console**

```
[ '5458c8de6c26bc741d41214b', '5458ceab5af5d17b1e207d8c' ]
```

How to handle this?

Comment: well, the name of the selects *are* meter_comp[], no wonder why the [] shows on the request body. Can't you change the names?

Comment: its dynamic select box.could be many number of select box.

Comment: Use `console.log(req.body['meter_comp[]'])` instead.